# Continuous Integration of Git on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, continuous-integration

assuming I'm running a small shop (3 devs) and using a Windows 7 machine as a centralised Git and IIS server what is the easiest way to get CI up and running?

This must be locally hosted CI (no github, no remote servers).

I'm doing C# .Net development with Visual Studio 2008.

Any help on getting this running with the minimum of effort and the nicest possible UI would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

TeamCity support Git natively now so I would recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

David,

You might also want to check out our Parabuild. It provides [Continuous Integration for Git](http://www.viewtier.com/products/parabuild/git_continuous_integration_release_management.htm) and runs .NET builds out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

- simple shared folder as mainstream repo
- CC.NET has a GIT support

Answer (score 1):

I've had experience with Hudson (Jenkins), Bamboo and Team City.

Team City is by far the best. It's easy to use but at the same time is advanced enough to allow you to configure your builds the way you want. All you have to do is download the installer and set it up on your CI box. And GIT along with other popular SCMs are natively supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your centralized Git repository is quite a bit easier to maintain if its sitting on a Linux box. Is this an option? If so, [check out this blog post](http://blog.commonthread.com/2008/4/14/setting-up-a-git-server). Yes, it really is that easy (on Linux).

As far as Continuous Integration, [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) + Git Plugin is great!

Comment: The link that "check out this blog post" points to has moved to here: http://blog.commonthread.com/post/1034988660/setting-up-a-git-server (HTH)

Answer (score -1):

For small teams like yours, Atlassian's [Bamboo Continuous Integration server](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) is a great solution and only cost <strike>$10</strike> $20 with our Starter license program (because it requires both JIRA & Bamboo, $10/mo each).  100% of the proceeds go to Room to Read, a great non-profit building schools and libraries for under-privileged children in developing countries.

Bamboo runs on Windows, Mac or Linux, and if you want to scale your build farm in the future, you can add more remote agents on premises or use elastic agents that run in the Amazon EC2 cloud.

To add Git support, you'll want to download and install the Bamboo Git plugin from plugins.atlassian.com.

Comment: Bamboo looks the most interesting so far... still seems to require more effort than I had hoped. May give it a try when I get a spare day somewhere.

Comment: Would feel happier if you declared that you work for Atlassian in a more explicit way (I only spotted it when you said 'our Starter license program). There's nothing technically wrong with your answer, but your answer is really just a free advert!